# Should I wrap a 3rd party library?

Tags: java, decorator, wrapper

I'm developing an application that manages many different components, including various objects in a Kubernetes cluster.

There's a nice Java [library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) to manage K8S objects, I use it to examine objects and manipulate them, but for most of the objects, I need some kind of a "wrapper-object" to store certain internal data of my application. For example, there's the `V1Pod` class, it's being used for K8S pods. An object of this class contains the list of related container objects (class `V1Container`) and so on and so forth. I need to keep some records about this pod, these records can't be kept in the K8S object, so I have to create my own object (we can call it `MyV1Pod`) with extra fields and a field containing a reference to the `V1Pod` object. Moreover, I also have to create my own objects of the `MyV1Container` class containing extra fields and references to the corresponding object of the `V1Container` class. And I have to keep the list of these `MyV1Container`-objects in `MyV1Pod`-object.

I find it a bit cumbersome to create a separate "wrapper" for each of all these classes. Is there any way to automate that? For example, when an application starts, it would scan all the classes in that library and create a "decorating" class for each of the classes that I need? For example, it would find the `V1Pod` class, create something like `MyV1Pod` and add a field containing a reference to the corresponding the `V1Pod` object and that additional fields that I need.

Something similar to the Decorator pattern, but with certain automation.

Or maybe I should go another way?

Any piece of advice would be very welcome!

Comment: Do your wrapper classes expose the same public methods as the Java library?

Comment: No, absolutely. They have their own methods and fields, their names are different.

Comment: What do these "wrapper" classes do? Sure they have additional fields and methods, but what *behavior* do they encapsulate --- what actions do they perform?

Comment: For example, it should keep the timestamp of the moment when this object's status had been updated. It also should keep a reference to the system (under the "system" word I mean the application, not K8S) account it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extra fields are the same between containers and pods, you could create a single wrapper class using generics.  Something like

```
class MyK8sWrapper<T> {
  private T k8sObject;
  private int extraField1;
  private int extraField2;

  public T getK8sObject() {
     return k8sObject;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you could probably script something to generate your container classes once then just use them.

Comment: Yes, this idea sounds good for my case, I thought about it too. Maybe there'll be other opinions, but if there aren't - I'll mark this answer as the best one.